# Combine Firebird Databases

Tags: firebird, database-migration

How can I do to the Firebird combine several databases into one? I tried fbexport but nothing compiles fbexport on Ubuntu, I keep getting this error.

```
g++ -pthread -lfbclient -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ ibpp/all_in_one.o fbcopy/args.o fbcopy/fbcopy.o fbcopy/TableDependency.o fbcopy/main.o  -oexe/fbcopy
ibpp/all_in_one.o: In function `ibpp_internals::GDS::Call()':
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5a5): undefined reference to `isc_create_database'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5ad): undefined reference to `isc_attach_database'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5b5): undefined reference to `isc_detach_database'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5bd): undefined reference to `isc_drop_database'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5c5): undefined reference to `isc_database_info'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `isc_open_blob2'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5d5): undefined reference to `isc_create_blob2'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5dd): undefined reference to `isc_close_blob'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5e5): undefined reference to `isc_cancel_blob'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5ed): undefined reference to `isc_get_segment'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5f5): undefined reference to `isc_put_segment'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x5fd): undefined reference to `isc_blob_info'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x605): undefined reference to `isc_array_lookup_bounds'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x60d): undefined reference to `isc_array_get_slice'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x618): undefined reference to `isc_array_put_slice'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x623): undefined reference to `isc_vax_integer'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x62e): undefined reference to `isc_sqlcode'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x639): undefined reference to `isc_sql_interprete'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `isc_interprete'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x64f): undefined reference to `isc_que_events'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x65a): undefined reference to `isc_cancel_events'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x665): undefined reference to `isc_start_multiple'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x670): undefined reference to `isc_commit_transaction'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x67b): undefined reference to `isc_commit_retaining'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x686): undefined reference to `isc_rollback_transaction'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x691): undefined reference to `isc_rollback_retaining'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x699): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_execute_immediate'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6a4): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_allocate_statement'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_describe'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6ba): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_describe_bind'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6c5): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_prepare'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_execute'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6db): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_execute2'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_fetch'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6f1): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_free_statement'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_set_cursor_name'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x707): undefined reference to `isc_dsql_sql_info'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x712): undefined reference to `isc_service_attach'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x71d): undefined reference to `isc_service_detach'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x728): undefined reference to `isc_service_start'
all_in_one.cpp:(.text+0x733): undefined reference to `isc_service_query'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [exe/fbcopy] Error 1
ubuntu@ip-10-252-116-132:/usr/local/src/fbexport-1.90$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

If exists a easier way than use fbexport it would be great.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this question, fix the compilation error or 'combine databases into one'? The latter would require some more explanation: do you want to merge multiple copies of the same database (which might require renumbering records), or different databases (with a disjunct set of tables)? As to the compile, your compile is probably missing a reference to ibase.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install firebird-dev headers after that you need to modify the Makefile with link flags at the end

```
exe/fbexport: $(OBJECTS_FBE) ibpp/all_in_one.o
g++ ibpp/all_in_one.o $(OBJECTS_FBE) -oexe/fbexport $(LINK_FLAGS)
```

please check the github version with fixes in the Makefile

https://github.com/mariuz/fbexport